# Dialog box not working - win32 api

Tags: c, windows, winapi

l making a program using MSVC++ 2010. The code compiles and the messagebox before the dialog procedure works but the dialog doesn't pop up. However if l take the same code to Dev-C++ it runs fine but the not all the dropdown list comboboxes shows.

```
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Run",L"Message",0);//Just for clarity
    DialogBox(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance,L"CHOICEBOX",hWnd,ComboDlg);
    return 0;

INT_PTR CALLBACK ComboDlg(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){//Dialog proc
int i=0; static int firsttime=1; PWSTR input=NULL;
switch(message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    //Dropdown combobox initialization
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
```

.

```
CHOICEBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 385, 279      //.rc
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Select Category"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
//comboboxes and static text controls
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the last comment on the chinese characters.

The data type to use **PCWSTR** instead of **const char * or PCSTR**.
So the correct syntax should be `PCWSTR Choice[]={L"string1", L"string2", L"etc"};`

Please also consider the L before each string this is because MSVC++ uses UNICODE OR UNICODE is turned on on the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In your resource file, replace `"Select Category"` with `L"Select Category"`, `"MS Shell Dlg"` with `L"MS Shell Dlg"`, etc.

And next time post a complete code which we can compile and test please.

Comment: Sorry, just that l feel that the whole code would be to much to post, that's why l cut it to size. However, you saved me.

Comment: Humm, The problem has comeback. When l restarted my system, the code compiles still the dialog does not work. Could the be something wrong by me? The link for the full source code is [link](http://pastebin.com/rhBNqjsr)

Comment: Nothing looks wrong. I tested it on my machine and It works. Here is the VS2013 solution without significant changes (only filenames and #includes may differ, and I have removed your icon which you hasn't sent): http://www.megafileupload.com/eeW7/Win32Project1.zip

Comment: Anyway, don't mix ANSI, Unicode and TCHAR strings. Use only one charset for one project. The recommended charset is Unicode or at least TCHAR.

Comment: *"Use only one charset for one project. [...] Unicode or at least TCHAR."* - This pretty much contradicts itself. `TCHAR` is used for **three** different character encodings (ASCII, MBCS, UTF16-LE).

Comment: @IInspectable I know that you know what I mean. I don't understand the point of commenting every thing I say. Please comment my typo errors too.

Comment: The point is simple: Consider **writing** what you mean, instead of writing *something*, and hope that *someone* might get, what you meant. I don't know what you meant by *"recommended charset is [...] at least TCHAR"*.

Comment: @mikedu95 Ok. l have fixed it but it displays a sort of chinese language in the dropdown list box instead of english language which l used as strings whenever l test run it.. Why? The source/the app can be downloaded from medialfire [link](http://download1647.mediafire.com/5jh2q95d88fg/dzugqxy3t18tgkt/Unical+PTUME.rar)

Comment: Your link is blocked by my proxy. Could you use megafileupload instead ? Can you also upload a screenshot of these chinese characters ?

Comment: @mikedu95 Thanks for your efforts, l had corrected the problem